# Finding a nonzero solution to system of equations in real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. I have got a system of equations:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
2x_2y_3-2x_3y_2&=&a\\
2x_3y_1-2x_1y_3&=&b\\
2x_1y_2-2x_2y_1&=&c.
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we choose $x_1,x_2,x_3$ first, then we will solve system of linear equations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-2x_3&2x_2\\
2x_3&0&-2x_1\\
-2x_2&2x_1&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}.$$ However, the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}
0&-2x_3&2x_2\\
2x_3&0&-2x_1\\
-2x_2&2x_1&0
\end{pmatrix}$ is $0$. So, we are not sure to choose $y_1,y_2,y_3$. Is there any way to find a nonzero solution (i.e $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ are not all $0$) to this system without solving for the variables explicitly?

Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: This is the equation of a cross product of two vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ by $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$
set equal to a third $\frac12(a,b,c)$. There is no unique solution. You can start from any vector, take its component orthogonal to
$(a,b,c)$, set this to $\vec x$, and construct $\vec y$ by taking the cross product of the other 2 vectors.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: Excuse me @R.J.Mathar, do you suggest how to solve if we add the equation $x_1x_4+x_2x_5+x_3x_6=d$ for some real number $d$?

Comment: Adding a requirement of the dot product of the vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ by the vector $(x_4,x_5,x_6)$ just specifies the angle between these two vectors. Still the components $x_{1,2,3}$ are not fixed because the dot product would only let $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be restricted to some cone around $(x_4,x_5,x_5)$ and that azimuth is still unspecified.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much @R.J.Mathar